# How can I start a terminal running vim with a input file

Tags: terminal, vim, macos

I can start a terminal running vim with :

```
open -a Terminal /usr/bin/vim
```

I'm trying to edit a file like:

```
open -a Terminal /usr/bin/vim --args $HOME/.bashrc
```

But `--args $HOME/.bashrc` has no effect at all.

Comment: have you tried without `--args`?

Comment: Yes, I did try without --args, no effect either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29510815/9447571 Doesn't look like there's a way to do what you want directly...